# Discontinuity of step function using open sets definition of continuity.

Tags: continuity, definition

> **Definition** A function $f : X \to Y$ between two topological spaces is continuous at $x$ if for any $V(f(x))$ open set containing $f(x)$ there's $U(x)$ open containing $x$ such that $f(U(x)) \subset V(f(x))$.

Consider $[0,1]$ with the subspace topology induced from $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. Defining the function

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & 0 \leq x < 1/2 \\
1 & 1/2 \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

I want to show that this function isn't continuous at $1/2$. I'm trying to learn how to apply the definition I stated.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and set $V(1) = (1 - \epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)$ I'm considering two cases.

1. $1 - \epsilon > 0$. This implies
   $f^{-1}(V(1)) = [1/2,1]$
2. $1 - \epsilon \leq 0$. This implies $f^{-1}(V(1)) = [0,1]$

This should cover all the cases, now from what I see here I have case 2) which is an open set in the induced topology, however 1) is not an open set. Therefore by 1) we can find an open sets in $Y$ such that there's no open set as pre-image, so $f$ is not continuous.

Am I applying the definition correctly?

Comment: There is a mistake in your definition of "$f$ is continuous at $x\in X$". Correct is to state that this is the case if for any open set $V$ with $f(x)\in V$ there is an open set $U$ with $x\in U$ and $U\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$ or equivalently $f(U)\subseteq V$. So not $V\subseteq f(U)$ is you say.

Comment: Your definition is not correct. You must replace the end by $f(U(x))\subset V(f(x))$

Comment: Corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to prove that $ f $ is Not continuous at $ \frac 12$, so you have to take the negation of your definition.

In other words, you should show that

$$\exists V(1)\;\;:\;\;\forall U(\frac 12)\;\; f(U(\frac 12))\not\subset V(1)$$

So, if we can take $$V(1)=(1-\frac 13,1+\frac 13)$$
and observe that

$$\forall \eta>0\;\; f((\frac 12-\eta, \frac 12+\eta))=\{0,1\}$$
and
$$\{0,1\}\not\subset (\frac 23,\frac 43)$$

Comment: Thanks for editing (not a subset) .

Comment: Can you both 1) point out the mistake I made and 2) comment more your answer as it's too short and I can't really follow. From you answer I got the negation and that you're picking $V(1)$ as you defined. But I don't understand your conclusion.

Comment: @user8469759 The inclusion symbol in the end of your definition has been inverted.